# How to implement material CircularProgressIndicator in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design

I am trying to show `CircularProgressIndicator` while my data are fetching from server but I get this error `root.findViewById(R.id.loadingbar) must not be null`.

## Logic

1. Hide recycler view items till data are fetched
2. Show `Circular Progress` while data are fetching
3. Hide `Circular Progress` when data are ready
4. Show recyclerview items

## Code

`xml`

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <!-- Circular progress indicator -->
    <com.google.android.material.progressindicator.CircularProgressIndicator
        android:id="@+id/loadingbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <!-- RecyclerView items -->
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:elevation="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/order_Iid"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:gravity="start|top"
            android:text="@string/order_ID"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/order_status_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|start"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
            android:text="@string/order_status"
            android:textColor="#5CDCBD"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/order_price_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top|end"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:text="@string/price"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

`Fragment`

> Code is commented for better understanding

```
class OrdersFragment : Fragment() {

    lateinit var sesssion: SessionManager
    lateinit var laundriesRecycler: RecyclerView
    lateinit var progressBar: CircularProgressIndicator
    lateinit var cardView2: CardView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_orders, container, false)
        sesssion = SessionManager(context)
        laundriesRecycler = root.findViewById(R.id.orders_list)


        // get progress
        progressBar = root.findViewById(R.id.loadingbar)
        //get recycler item
        cardView2 = root.findViewById(R.id.cardView2)

        getOrders()
        return root
    }

    private fun getOrders() {

        //show progress
        progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        //hide items
        cardView2.visibility = View.GONE




        var session = SessionManager(context)
        session.checkLogin()
        var user = session.getUserDetails()
        var token: String? = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_ACCESS_TOKEN)
        val tokenFull = "Bearer $token"

        val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context)
        val url = "https://example.com/api/orders"

        val stringReq : StringRequest =
                object : StringRequest(
                        Method.GET, url,
                        Response.Listener { response ->


                            // hide progress
                            progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                            //show items
                            cardView2.visibility = View.VISIBLE



                            val list = Gson().fromJson(response, OrderArr::class.java)
                            laundriesRecycler.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
                            laundriesRecycler.adapter = OrdersAdapter(context, list)
                        },
                        Response.ErrorListener { error ->
                            Toast.makeText(context, error.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show()
                        }
                ){
                    override fun getHeaders(): Map<String, String> {
                        val headers = HashMap<String, String>()
                        headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
                        headers["Authorization"] = tokenFull
                        return headers
                    }
                }
        queue.add(stringReq)
    }
}
```

**Any idea?**

Comment: Maybe you should consider using `ViewBinding`? It can reduce these NPE error

Comment: @Teo how? can you give an example?

Comment: And also, you might need to change your question to `root.findViewById(R.id.loadingbar) must not be null` to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solved

Special thanks to `Teo` who made me realize the issue.

#### Fixes

1. Instead of having my progress inside my items xml I had to add it into my fragment xml where my recycler code placed (#1 misplaced code)
2. Using binding (unlike Teo mentioned , there is no need to use `onViewCreated` infact that cause undefined `binding` error. Instead it should be defined inside `onCreateView` function) Here is the final code

```
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentOrdersBinding
    
    override fun onCreateView(
      inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
      savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
      // Inflate the layout for this fragment
      val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_orders, container, false)
      sesssion = SessionManager(context)
      laundriesRecycler = root.findViewById(R.id.orders_list)
      binding = FragmentOrdersBinding.bind(root) // <--here
      getOrders()
      return root
    }
    
    private fun getOrders() {
      binding.loadingBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
      binding.ordersList.visibility = View.GONE
      
      // API process and flip those 2 lines above in success response to
      binding.loadingBar.visibility = View.GONE
      binding.ordersList.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In you build.gradle(app)

```
android{
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
        dataBinding = true
    }
}
```

```
// 1 - direct inflate the fragment layout into Fragment()
class OrdersFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_orders) {

    // 2 - view binding
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentOrdersBinding
    lateinit var sesssion: SessionManager
    lateinit var laundriesRecycler: RecyclerView
    lateinit var progressBar: CircularProgressIndicator
    lateinit var cardView2: CardView

    // 3 - directly call onViewCreated() as the layout already inflated
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        
       // 4 - bind view to viewBinding variable
        binding = FragmentOrdersBinding.bind(view)
        sesssion = SessionManager(context)
        getOrders()
    }

    private fun getOrders() {
        
        // 5 - After that, basically every element just call binding to locate them
        //show progress
        binding.loadingBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        //hide items
        binding.cardView2.visibility = View.GONE

    }
}
```

Comment: cannot find `binding.loadingbar.visibility = View.VISIBLE` the `loadingbar` is red

Comment: Can you try to type `binding.`? The IDE will suggest the correct value to you

Comment: cannot find it. Here is screenshot https://ibb.co/5rpmnRk

Comment: try to add `dataBinding = true` in your gradle. I think it's belongs to databinding instead of viewBinding

Comment: what if i simply use `loadingBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE` and not using `binding`?

Comment: That's so-called `ViewBinding` I think. But it is using Kotlin synthetics and this library will soon deprecated, it is better to stick with `Binding` 

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration

Comment: By using `binding.`, it is more stable as you target it to corresponding layout.

Comment: ok, but still the error exist (cannot find the id)

Comment: i think i got the issue, testing,,,

Comment: Ok I've fixed it, I will vote up your answer because it was the reason I figure it out but I will publish working solution. Thank you so much.

Comment: Thanks for your upvote, hope it helps :)

Comment: it definitely did, appreciate it